# Aspell - special characters in a custom dictionary

Tags: php, spell-checking, aspell

I want to use Aspell with the custom dictionaries for spell checking in Angular + PHP application (extension mekras/php-speller). The problem is that I can't add some specific words to the dictionary provided by the users (default dictionaries works great).

Is it even possible to add custom words with "special characters" like productDW40 or Special©? For now code returns message:  The word "productDW40" is invalid. The character '4' (U+34) may not appear in the middle of a word.\n".

Default encoding is UTF-8.

If it's not possible then maybe someone can recommend another solutions or external services for spell checking?

Thank you in advance.